# How to get all file Present in plugin

Tags: java, eclipse

I have eclipse Plug-in project i want to know all files present in that plug-in.

For example i have plug-in "com.sample.sam" i want to know which all files present in this plug-in.
Requirement is to collect all file having specific extension(File extension is known) in that plug-in but i do not know file name.

Comment: Do you want this in a plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go to **'eclipse\plugins'** of your eclipse IDE(on your local HD), and use search option. Suppose you want all the files having .sam extension, then simply search for *.sam